# Not getting auth.currentUser after registration until I reload the page (VUE3 + Quasar + Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, quasar-framework

Facing a little issue in regards to user registration. Everything works fine except this one detail where I have to reload the page after user registration or else their data will not render. I am displaying the username on the Navbar once they log in/register so this is not ideal.

Here is my App.vue:

```js
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import { useAuthStore } from "stores/auth";

const storeAuth = useAuthStore();

onMounted(() => {
  storeAuth.init();
});
</script>
```

Here is my init() function in the auth Store:

```js
init() {
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.user.id = user.uid;
          this.user.email = user.email;
          this.user.displayName = user.displayName;
        } else {
          this.user = {};
        }
      });
```

and in the Registration Form component, this is the function that triggers when clicking SUBMIT:

```js
\\ Triggering Firebase registration and opening a confirmation modal if successful.

const onSubmit = () => {
  storeAuth.registerUser(credentials);
  registered.value = true;
};

\\When the user clicks OK in the confirmation modal he/she is redirected to their profile page

function redirectUser() {
  const id = auth.currentUser.uid;
  router.push({ name: "user", params: { id } });
}
```

and finally, this is the registerUser method in the auth Store:

```js
registerUser(credentials) {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        credentials.email,
        credentials.password
      )
        .then((userCredential) => {
          console.log(userCredential);
          const user = userCredential.user;
          updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
            displayName: credentials.displayName,
          });
          setDoc(doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid), {
            displayName: credentials.displayName,
            email: credentials.email,
            countryCode: credentials.countryCode,
            phoneNumber: `+${credentials.countryCode.value}${credentials.phoneNumber}`,
            userType: "Persona",
            uid: auth.currentUser.uid,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error.message: ", error.message);
        });
    }
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Basically I want to avoid having to refresh the page for the displayName to appear in the NavBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of `user.diplayName` name is `null`. Although you are using `updateProfile()` to set a value, but you are not handling the promises correctly. First, try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
// async function
async registerUser(credentials) {
  const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email, credentials.password)

  await updateProfile(user, {
    displayName: credentials.displayName
  });

  await setDoc(doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid), {
    displayName: credentials.displayName,
    email: credentials.email,
    countryCode: credentials.countryCode,
    phoneNumber: `+${credentials.countryCode.value}${credentials.phoneNumber}`,
    userType: "Persona",
    uid: auth.currentUser.uid,
  });
}
```

The profile may not update right away. You can use `reload()` to reload current user's data.

```
// add this after updateProfile()
await reload(user);
```

You are updating the state from inside of `onAuthStateChanged()` that'll trigger right after user is signed in. It'll be best to update the displayName in state manually in case of registration after `updateProfile()`.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's still not working but it's probably just because I am having some trouble with the manually updating displayName part. I should not be declaring this.user.displayName = user.displayName in the onAuthStateChanged method then with the uid and email?

Comment: @DirkGaston as mentioned, the `onAuthStateChanged()` does not trigger after you run `updateProfile()` so the state will just not update. You would have to update the manually there.